# Has anyone been diagnosed with PTSD and been able to get a first class medical?

Tags: medical

Any input on getting a medical with PTSD is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

..."*the FAA can still consider you for certification even if you are receiving counseling for PTSD.*" [[1]](https://thepilotlawyer.com/faa-medical-and-va-benefits-for-ptsd/)

The [Guide for Aviation Medical Examiners](https://www.faa.gov/ame_guide/media/PTSDDispositionTable.pdf) has a [Post-Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD) Decision Tool for the AME](https://www.faa.gov/ame_guide/media/PTSDDecisionToolfortheAME.pdf)

..."*may not even require you to have a psychiatric evaluation, but you can anticipate that the FAA will ask for more information about your case and application.*"[[2]](https://www.aviationpsychiatry.com/faq/ptsd/)

See also: [this](https://www.aviationmedicine.com/article/disability-insurance-and-faa-medical-reporting-what-is-a-pilot-to-do-lets-be-honest/) and [that](https://pic.aopa.org/discuss/viewtopic/168/2070).